# iOS postgres in docker-compose with port mapping

Tags: ios, postgresql, docker, psql

I have the following docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
  container_name: test-psql
  image: postgres:10.4-alpine
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  volumes:
    - ~/docker_data/postgres:/data/postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: test
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
    POSTGRES_DB: test
```

I start everything with `docker-compose up` and then `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE         COMMAND         CREATED      STATUS       PORTS         NAMES
f4cae94afaa6    postgres:10.4-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 seconds ago    Up 47 seconds    0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   test-psql
```

But when trying to connect to it with `psql`

```
psql -h localhost -U test
```

I get the error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
     Is the server running on host “localhost” (::1) and accepting
     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
     Is the server running on host “localhost” (127.0.0.1) and accepting
     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying is correct - I tested it on my end just in case and it's working as intended. I'd suggest checking your firewall configuration.

Comment: How do I check the firewall for that?

Comment: @wasp256 Which operating system are you using?

Comment: iOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: I checked the firewall and it's turned off

Comment: Yeah makes sense - iOS doesn't run with firewall by default. Can you give it a try with the following command instead: "psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U test"

Comment: Tried it but same result